# Second to last element of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Consider the following function for finding the second-to-last element of a list:

```
myButLast (x:xs) = if length xs > 1 then myButLast xs else x
```

This is an O(n^2) algorithm, because `length xs` is O(n) and is called O(n) times. What is the most elegant way to write this in Haskell such that `length` stops once it gets past 1, so that the algorithm is O(n)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is to avoid `length`:

```
myButLast (x : _ : []) = x  -- base case
myButLast (_ : xs)     = myButLast xs
```

The definitive reference on patterns in Haskell is the language report: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17

GHC implements a few extensions described at https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#pattern-guards.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you could pattern match like that! Where can I find the full restrictions on pattern matching?

Comment: @RenéG Added to the answer.

Comment: Also: you should change `(x:_:[])` to `[x,_]`

Comment: @RenéG I think the first form is easier for beginners (fewer special cases in patterns).

Answer (score 6):

what about

```
myButLast []     = error "oho"
myButLast [x,_]  = x
myButLast (_:xs) = myButLast xs
```

Answer (score 5):

Exploiting `zip`:

```
\l -> fst . last $ zip l (tail l)
```

Also available in a pointless, obfuscated style:

```
fst . last . (zip <*> tail)
```

or even without parentheses (thanks to @melpomene):

```
fst . last . ap zip tail
```

Other variants:

```
last . ap (zipWith const) tail
```

Comment: `fst . last . ap zip tail` - no parens!

Comment: yeah for the Kleene *trick* :D (... did you know that I cannot start a comment with "+1" here anymore?)

Comment: If you're going to go partial, why not `last . init`?

Comment: @Carsten: +1/-1 comments [have been](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277314/should-we-discourage-leading-1-on-comments) disabled [for a while](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278161/users-working-around-the-1-comment-block).

Comment: One great thing is that this generalizes *efficiently* to nth-from-last.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution:

```
myButLast [] = error "List is empty"
myButLast [x] = error "List is a singleton"
myButLast xs = last $ init xs
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using the tail function from prelude

```
myButLast :: [Int] -> Maybe Int
myButLast (x:xs) | ((null xs) || null (tail xs)) = Just x
                 | otherwise                     = myButLast(xs)
myButLast []                                     = Nothing
```

Comment: (correction to my previous comment:) calling `myButLast [1]` will cause an error, because `tail []` is an error. This could be fixed with `not (null xs) && null (tail xs)`, for example.

Comment: Thanks @WillNess . The code now returns the sole entry when it can't find the penultimate element. The fix was in using ((null xs) || null (tail xs))

Answer (score 1):

Another zip-based solution, without exlicitly zipping. Throw in some safety for good measure.

```
import Data.Maybe

g :: Int -> [a] -> Maybe a
g i = (head <$>) . listToMaybe . reverse         -- quick'n'dirty safe-last
                 . getZipList . traverse ZipList 
                 . sequence [id, drop i] 

g  1 [1..10] => Just 9
g  3 [1..10] => Just 7
g 13 [1..10] => Nothing
```